# QueryBuilder and sub-conditions

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

Hi i'm tring to build query using `QueryBuilder` and `Query\Expr`. 
My probleme is build sub condition like in order to get a list of model for all of this conditions ?

- `Status` is `true` and not in list of `model` name
- `Status` is `false` and not in other list of `model` name

**Code :**

```
public function process(QueryBuilder $qb)
{
   $cond1 = new Expr\Andx;
   $cond1->add($qb->expr()->eq('status', 0);
   $cond2= new Expr\Andx;
   $cond2->add($qb->expr()->notIn('model', array('308','408'));
   $cond1->add($cond2);

   $cond3 = new Expr\Andx;
   $cond3->add($qb->expr()->eq('status', 1);
   $cond4= new Expr\Andx;
   $cond4->add($qb->expr()->notIn('model', array('A1','A2'));
   $cond3->add($cond4);

   $qb->andWhere($cond1); 
   $qb->andWhere($cond3); 
}
```

**class Model**

```
Class Vehicle{
    /**
    * @var string
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="model", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
    */
    private $modele;

    /**
    * @var string
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="make", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
    */
    private $make;

    /**
    * @var boolean (status for vehicule 1 = Used vehicle)
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="boolean")
    * @Serializer\Groups({"list", "details"})
    */
    private $status;

    //-- Other properties, getter & setter

}
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Do you even need those? :) Yes, those make query more readable but logic-wise they might not matter at all...

Comment: @JovanPerovic : Yes I need `Query Builder` and `Expr`. Cause : query is build by collection of filters ...

Comment: Sorry, I was under impression that you need to wrap the whole query with `(` and `)` and my comment was about that ;)

Comment: are you sure that you are looking for something that have status and not status? or the tuple are in OR condition?

Comment: @Matteo i need list of `model` isn't in list of `model` in a case `status` and not in another list in case `!status`. you're maybe true i don't know how doing this query :s

Comment: possibily an `OR` condition? so (new vehicle of model 308,408) OR (used vehicle of model A1,A2)?

Comment: @Matteo `Or` is actualy a good idea. I'm working to find an implementation cause of app complexity the `model` list is two `array` (one for used vehicle, one for new) who should be excluded of the list of `vehicles`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Matteo & pcm

```
$qb->andWhere(
    $qb->expr()->orX(
        $qb->expr()->andX($qb->expr()->eq("status", 0), $qb->expr()->notIn("model", $listNewModel)),
        $qb->expr()->andX($qb->expr()->eq("status", 1), $qb->expr()->notIn("model", $listUsedModel));
    )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

```php
$qb->andWhere(
  $qb->expr()->andx(
    $qb->expr()->andx(
      $qb->expr()->eq('status', 0),
      $qb->expr()->andx(
        $qb->expr()->notLike('model', '308'),
        $qb->expr()->notLike('model', '408')
      )
    ),
    $qb->expr()->andx(
      $qb->expr()->eq('status', 1),
      $qb->expr()->andx(
        $qb->expr()->notLike('model', 'A1'),
        $qb->expr()->notLike('model', 'A2')
      )
    )
  )
);
```

You can go wild with nesting expressions as long as you read the [docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#the-expr-class)

Let me know if you need help :)

Comment: try to print out the query and see what it produces with this command $qb->>getSql();

Comment: As say Matteo i think the problem is status and not status i don't know how to write this

Comment: eq('status', true) if the status field is boolean. maybe put some entity code here so I can help

Comment: I have updated my answer to fit your needs. You have the tools in your hand, just need to use them accordingly :)

Comment: By the way, always try to dump the raw sql to see what your expressions produce.

Comment: same probleme with status =0 and status = 1 can't give result :s